# Cloudwatch Config with timestamped logfile

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to set cloudwatch logs from an EC2 instance in AWS , here is the configuration

```
{
        "agent": {
                        "run_as_user": "root"
        },              
        "logs": {       
                "logs_collected": {
                        "files": {
                        "collect_list": [
                                {
                                "file_path": "/var/log/test.log",
                                "log_group_name": "my-app",
                                "log_stream_name": "my-app-instance-id"
                                }
                        ]       
                }       
                }       
        }
}
```

This does not create the specified log group as expected after starting the cloudwatch agent as

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json -s
```

There are no errors seen on the console but the specified log group isnt found in the AWS console. IS this configuration supposed to create this log group?
The other thought that comes to mind is that under `var/log` the name of the log file is appended with a timstamp as `test-20200407.log` is this the issue? How can I account for the timestamp?

Comment: Have you tried "file_path": "/var/log/test-*" ? Wildcard entry? Does it work?

Comment: I have not but the thing is there are multiple files with different time stamps

Comment: What is the exact requirement? You have files as test-<timestamp>.log and you want CW to fetch logs for test.log? or all the files starting with "test"? or any specific file?

Comment: There are a couple of files that get generated with a time stamp of today and yesterday and I want all logs continuously watched by cloudwatch

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to continuously monitor the log files, it means, whatever file "test-.log" is updates, should be pushed to CW console.

This can be done with wildcards. Something as below :

```
    "collect_list": [
    {
    "file_path": "/var/log/test*",
    "log_group_name": "my-app",
    "log_stream_name": "my-app-instance-id"
    }
]
```

You can find the reference for the same at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=156280

> The 'file' option specifies files that you want to push. It can point to a specific file or multiple files with wildcards, such as /var/log/system.log*. **Only the latest file is pushed based on file modification time**.